# Setup project Window Handler in CustomActions class

Tags: c#, windows-installer, custom-action

I have a CustomInstaller class (System.Configuration.Install.Installer) and basically I'm opening a dialog form at Install method.
I wonder if it's possible somehow to say that 'Parent' property of that form would be the setup process window?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the handle of the installer window.  Not so sure how to get it, but Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle ought to give you good odds.  Then create a NativeWindow to wrap the handle so you can use it as the owner.  Like this:

```
        IntPtr hdl = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
        var window = new NativeWindow();
        window.AssignHandle(hdl);
        try {
            using (var dlg = new YourForm()) {
                var result = dlg.ShowDialog(window);
                //...
            }
        }
        finally {
            window.ReleaseHandle();
        }
```

Comment: I got that... it's because windows installer starts CustomActions in different process, but in the same tree...

Answer (score 0):

As a simple complement since I looked for the same answer to prevent the MSI main window to overlap my popup:

```
var thatmsihandle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;
```

An easy wrapper would be:

```
internal class WindowHandler
{
    internal NativeWindow MainWindow { get; private set;}

    internal WindowHandler()
    {
        MainWindow = new NativeWindow();
        MainWindow.AssignHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle);
    }

    internal void Dispose()
    {
        MainWindow.ReleaseHandle();
    }
}
```

Thanks for the pointer nonetheless saved a lot of time!

EDIT: it seems not to work in fact, good old FindWindowA did the trick